# Handling paragraphs in files unix

Tags: linux

I created text file in linux containing three paragraphs. so now I want to display each paragraph with line numbers in result while displaying the content of file.

Content of my file is something like.

```
      Below are content navigation systems to help you browse theencyclopedia. They serve as an alternative to the search.

      Below are content navigation systems to help you browse the encyclopedia. They serve as an alternative to the search.

      Below are content navigation systems to help you browse the encyclopedia. They serve as an alternative to the search.
```

Now I want to print result as

1      Below are content..........(for first paragraph)

2      Below are content..........(for second paragraph) and so on.

each paragraph in file contains one line gap

As well as I also need to print the last paragraph only from the above file by using another command.

I am using ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Perl, [paragraph mode](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlrun.pod) `-00`, print input lines `-p` plus a custom prefix with the number.

```
% (echo hi; echo; echo there) | perl -00 -pe 'print ++$x, " "'
```

Last paragraph would be

```
% (echo hi; echo; echo there) | perl -00 -ne '$l=$_; END { print $l }'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk` to add paragraph numbers.  Say your file is called `input` you could do:

```
awk 'BEGIN {para=1} !/^\s*$/ {printf "%d %s\n", para, $0; para+=1;next};1' input
```

this will keep a counter of the number of paragraphs we've seen and every time there is a none-blank line it will add the current counter to the front, then increment the counter.

To get the last paragraph you could similarly use awk, assuming there might be blank lines at the end that you do not want:

```
awk '!/^\s*$/ {line=$0} END{print line}' input
```

Comment: Yes thank you ,thats worked for me and I will google for awk and all the parameters.

Comment: And plz can you tell me how to display only last paragraph from file. This will be a great help

Comment: @Joshi awk is a powerful tool that will take some time to learn, but will be worth the investment.  Also, I've updated the answer to show one way of getting the last paragraph, if you don't have to worry about blank lines at the end you could just do `tail -n 1` on the file though

Comment: Ok thank you very much @Eric I will invest my time to learn awk.

Comment: awk 'BEGIN {para=1} !/^\s*$/ {printf "%d %s\n", para, $0; \n +=1;next};1'

Comment: this was worked fine If I copy the paragraph from somewhere in file but failed while entering content of file manually. so I just modifed it as follow

Comment: awk 'BEGIN {para=1} /^\t/ {printf "%d %s\n", para, $0; para+=1;next}{print $0};'

Comment: And once again thanks @Eric for suggesting awk. its very interesting